# Scraping text on google translate page - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio, node-fetch

I'm trying to scrape a few pieces of text from this URL https://translate.google.ca/?sl=en&tl=zh-TW&text=Hello&op=translate

So far I have one piece working, but I can't figure out how to get the other two.

I'm trying to get the original text (eng), the Chinese character (character) and the Pinyin (cn)

Here is what I have - the eng is working but I can't get the cn or character to work.

```
import fetch from "node-fetch"
import cheerio from "cheerio"

const getRawData = (URL) => {
  return fetch(URL)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
      return data;
    });
};

const URL = "https://translate.google.ca/?sl=en&tl=zh-TW&text=Hello&op=translate";

const getData = async () => {
  const data = await getRawData(URL);
  const $ = cheerio.load(data);

  const eng = $("div.D5aOJc")[0].children[0].data
  const cn = $("div.kO6q6e")[0].data
  const character = $("span.Q4iAWc").data

  console.log(eng, cn, character);
};

getData();
```

Comment: Why you need to scrape to take the translations? Google already has Translation API

Comment: To help with a project, mostly practice

Comment: Translate is somewhat a Dynamic page. I am recommending something like Puppeteer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sandun Isuru Niraj said, you need a Puppeteer. Here is the solution to your problem:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const queryup = "Hello";
const query = encodeURI(queryup);

async function GTranslate(searchQuery) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`https://translate.google.ca/?sl=en&tl=zh-TW&text=${searchQuery}&op=translate`);
  await page.waitForSelector(".Q4iAWc");

  const eng = await page.$eval(".D5aOJc.Hapztf", (el) => el.textContent);
  const cn = await page.$eval(".dePhmb .kO6q6e", (el) => el.textContent);
  const character = await page.$eval(".Q4iAWc", (el) => el.textContent);

  console.log(eng, cn, character);

  await browser.close();
}

GTranslate(query);
```

Output:

```
Hello Nǐ hǎo 你好
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And it works with a for loop!